# SQL To MS Access SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hello SQL/MS Access community! I have a problem! I have a query in SQL that gets the top record for each group and it works great! However, I need this to be a query in Microsoft Access. Is there anyone out there that can help me with translating it? I do not know coding at all (I can pick it apart to understand it, but I can't write it unfortunately). Any help is much appreciated!

`SELECT *
FROM Table1;
WITH summary AS (
    SELECT p.PK_ID,
           p.Field1,
           p.Field2,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.PK_ID
                              ORDER BY p.Field1 DESC) AS rk
    FROM Table1 p)
SELECT s.*
   FROM summary s
  WHERE s.rk=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the first record (based on `Field1`) for each `pk_id`.  Something like this may work for you:

```
select p.*
from table1 as p
where p.field1 = (select max(p2.field1)
                  from table1 as p2
                  where p2.pk_id = p.pk_id
                 );
```